# Combinar intervention Image Laravel, Vuejs y axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

estoy tratando de almacenar un formulario en una base de datos usando laravel, vuejs y axios.
En dicho formulario tengo un campo de tipo file para almacenar fotos. Anteriormente cuando trabajaba solamente con laravel usaba un complemento que se llama Intervention Image. que consiste en almacenar la imagen en la carpeta publica y el nombre de la imagen en la base de datos.. Mi pregunta es.. Esto lo puede replicar con vuejs y axios? y si se puede.. como se hace?

Mi funcion store del controlador

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    if(!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');
    $equipo = new Equipo();
    $equipo->eq_nombre = $request->eq_nombre;
    $equipo->eq_descripcion = $request->eq_descripcion;
    $equipo->id_categoria = $request->id_categoria;
    if(Input::hasFile('eq_foto')) {
        $file=Input::file('eq_foto');
        Image::make($request->file('eq_foto'))
            ->resize(144, 145)
            ->save(public_path().'/imagenes/equipos/' . $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $empresa->eq_foto=$file->getClientOriginalName();
        // var_dump($empresa->eq_foto=$file->getClientOriginalName()); die;
    }
    $equipo->eq_condicion = 1;
    $equipo->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $equipo->save();

}
```

Mi formulario

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="text-input">Ingrese el nombre del Equipo</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" onKeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13) event.returnValue = false;" v-model="eq_nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre del equipo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="text-input">Ingrese la descripcion del Equipo</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" onKeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13) event.returnValue = false;" v-model="eq_descripcion" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la descripcion del equipo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="text-input">Categoría</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <select class="form-control" v-model="id_categoria">
                                <option value="0" disabled>Seleccione</option>
                                <option v-for="categoria in arrayCategoria" :key="categoria.id" :value="categoria.id" v-text="categoria.cat_nombre">
                                </option>
                            </select>                                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="text-input">Ingrese el logo del Equipo</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="file" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div v-show="errorEquipo" class="form-group row div-error">
                        <div class="text-center text-error">
                            <div v-for="error in errorMostrarMsjEquipo" :key="error" v-text="error">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Mi funcion que hace la peticion

```
registrarEquipo() {
            if(this.validarEquipo()) {
                return;
            }
            let me = this;
            axios.post('/equipo/registrar', {
                // junto a la url pasamos los parametros que se van a guardar
                'eq_nombre' : this.eq_nombre,
                'eq_descripcion' : this.eq_descripcion,
                'id_categoria': this.id_categoria,
                'eq_foto': this.eq_foto

            }).then(function (response) {
                // si todo sale bien
                me.cerrarModal();
                // llama a listar fecha y le pasamos la pagina, palabra a buscar y campo
                me.listarEquipo(1, '', 'eq_nombre');


            }).catch(function (error) {
                // si todo sale mal XD;
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
```

Este codigo me funciona.. guarda todo bien.. Pero la imagen no.. No se como tratarlo.

Comment: de que tipo es eq_foto? que es donde va el archivo, no?

Comment: Exacto.. es la variable donde debe ir el archivo

Comment: Y que esta viajando ahi? porque lo que estas haciendo, parece que esta bien...

Comment: Veras.. tengo este input <input type="file" class="form-control">, pero no se como enlazarlo a mi variable, para que vaya al controlador por que en el no se puede usar la directiva v-model="eq_foto", porque sale un error de que tengo que usar v-onchage"", y ahi es donde me trabo porque no se como usarlo

Comment: ahh.. ahi esta el problema.. y ese es el error que deberiamos estar mirando. Vos deberias poder enlazar tu input type=file a un v_model. que error recibis?

Comment: Error File inputs are read only. Use a v-on:change listener instead. Laravel Vuejs este es el error

Answer (score 0):

Para trabajar con archivos en Vue.Js como tu mismo dices debes de poner el evento onChange en tu input file:

```
<input type="file" @change="getFile">
```

Luego en la función definida trabajas la data como mas te convenga, te dejo un ejemplo con el cual puedes probar la captura del archivo.

```
data: () => ({
   file: ''
}),
methods: {
  getFile(event) {
     let file = event.target;
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
           // aca tienes dos opciones enviar la imagen en un form data o como base64 
           var reader = new FileReader();
               reader.onload = (e) => {
                    let imageData = e.target.result;
                    this.file = this.imageData.split(',')[1];
               }
               reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Y dentro de la condicionante que hago ? almaceno el input.files dentro de mi variable eq_foto? o como..

Comment: Te añadi la funcionalidad para convertir el archivo en base64, ahora tienes que enviar `this.file` a tu controlador y trabajarlo